# Pandas: How to convert series with an integer/fraction mix into a whole number

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I'm iterating thru Excel columns containing numbers and I'm trying to round all the numbers using .apply(pd.to_numeric).round()

This has always worked for me but recently, some of the Excel files contain columns with numbers mixed with fractions (e.g. 27 3/8, 50 17/32).  When my script runs, I get "Unable to parse string "50 17/32" at position 0"

Suppose this is my series:

```
0           250.25
1           32.75
2           64
3           50 17/32
4           16 3/8
Name: Qty, dtype: object
```

Desired result:

```
0           250
1           33
2           64
3           51
4           16
Name: Qty, dtype: object
```

I'm trying to split the columns based on the white space and somehow trying to add the 2 columns together, but I'm running into all sorts of issues.  The code below sort of works, but my original 'Qty' column is returning a bunch of NaNs instead of the original numbers for rows where there is no delimiter character

```
df['Qty'] = df['Qty'].fillna(value=np.nan)
df[['Qty','Fraction']] = df['Qty'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
```

Here's my original ['Qty'] column:

[image]

Here's the same rows after running that split code on it:

[image]

Intertingly, it does properly split the rows with integer-fraction mix, but turning certain rows to NaN for reasons I don't understand is throwing me off.  Another thing I've tried is using lambda functions, but from what I can gather, those work best when it's just a traditional fraction like 3/8, without an integer in front of it.  Been researching for hours and I'm close to giving up so if anyone has a clue how to go about this, I'd love to know

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python- Convert a mixed number to a float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878727/python-convert-a-mixed-number-to-a-float)

Comment: To elaborate: the linked question shows you how to do this for a single number. If you use `Series.apply()`, you can apply a function across many rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html):

```
from fractions import Fraction
df2 = df['Qty'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\s*(\d+/\d+)?')

out = (pd.to_numeric(df2[0], errors='coerce')
      +df2[1].fillna(0).apply(lambda x: float(Fraction(x)))
      )
df['float'] = out
df['int'] = out.round().astype(int)
```

output:

```
        Qty      float  int
0    250.25  250.25000  250
1     32.75   32.75000   33
2        64   64.00000   64
3  50 17/32   50.53125   51
4    16 3/8   16.37500   16
```

Alternative using arithmetic:

```
df2 = df['Qty'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\s*(?:(\d+)/(\d+))?').astype(float)
df['int'] = (df2[0]+df2[1].fillna(0)/df2[2].fillna(1)).round().astype(int)
```

Comment: This works fine, but for some reason the surrounding numbers that do not have a / are getting converted into NaNs.  Probably some issue with Excel, I suppose I'll just figure out a way to compare the 2 columns and get the max value.  Regardless, your code works based on my specific question, so thank you